# Monogame Windows Phone 8 OnExiting not called

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xna, monogame, 2d-games

I am learning MonoGame on Windows Phone 8 and in my code I have the following method inside my game class to detect if the game is exiting when user press the Start button but it's not being called.

```
protected override void OnExiting(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    // There’s no going back from here, so save everything and exit.
    SaveGameState();
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is technically a bug in MonoGame because it doesn't behave the same way as XNA. However, there is an [explanation and a workaround](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/issues/564).

On some platforms such as iOS and Android the game never really exits; therefore doing something in the OnExiting method won't work the way you expect on those platforms anyway.

So it's a good idea to save game state in the [OnDeactivated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.ondeactivated.aspx) method and re-load it in the [OnActivated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.onactivated.aspx) method instead.